# Query to retrieve incomplete records by month

Tags: oracle

Given this sample data in an Oracle database:

| ID | Step | StartDate | CompDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 98775 | 4.24 | 28-Jun-23 |  |
| 98776 | 4.31 | 28-Jun-23 | 5-Jul-23 |
| 98777 | 4.24 | 28-Jun-23 |  |
| 98845 | 4.31 | 26-Jul-23 | 2-Aug-23 |
| 98846 | 4.31 | 27-Jul-23 | 27-Jul-23 |
| 98847 | 4.24 | 31-Jul-23 |  |
| 98848 | 4.31 | 31-Jul-23 | 2-Aug-23 |
| 98853 | 4.31 | 3-Aug-23 | 3-Aug-23 |
| 98854 | 4.24 | 3-Aug-23 |  |
| 98855 | 4.23 | 3-Aug-23 |  |

I need a query that will return the remaining records by month.  The query should return values like this:

To explain what I need, in the sample data above, 3 records were created during June.  Of those 3 records, 0 were completed during June, so the remaining records count for June is 3.  In July, 4 records were created, 1 from June and 1 from July were completed.  This means that, at the end of July, 5 records remained from the ones created during June and July.  In August, 3 records were created, 2 from July were completed, and 1 from August was completed.  The remaining count for August is 5.  I need a running total of tasks not yet completed for each month.

| ColumnName | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06 | 3 |
| 2023-07 | 5 |
| 2023-08 | 5 |

I've tried this query but the counts are off:

```
WITH record_creations AS (
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(startdate, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
        COUNT(id) AS created_records
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE id in (98775,98776,98777,98845,98846,98847,98848,98853,98854,98855)
    GROUP BY
        TO_CHAR(startdate, 'YYYY-MM')
),
records_incomplete AS (
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(compdate, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
        COUNT(id) AS remaining_records
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        compdate IS  NULL
        and id in (98775,98776,98777,98845,98846,98847,98848,98853,98854,98855)
    GROUP BY
        TO_CHAR(compdate, 'YYYY-MM')
)
SELECT
    NVL(c.month, i.month) AS ColumnName,
    NVL(created_records, 0) - NVL(remaining_records, 0) AS records
FROM
    record_creations c
    FULL OUTER JOIN records_incomplete i ON c.month = i.month
ORDER BY
    NVL(c.month, i.month)
```

This query returns this:

| ColumnName | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06 | 3 |
| 2023-07 | 4 |
| 2023-08 | 3 |

Comment: What does "remaining records by month" mean? Where do values you posted as desired result come from? Could you explain rules which lead from sample source data to desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive query to generate all the months and then count how many projects have started before the end of each month but have not yet finished:

```sql
WITH months (month, endmonth) AS (
  SELECT MIN(TRUNC(startdate, 'MM')),
         MAX(TRUNC(compdate, 'MM'))
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(month, 1),
         endmonth
  FROM   months
  WHERE  month < endmonth
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(month, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   table_name
         WHERE  startdate <  ADD_MONTHS(m.month, 1)
         AND    (  compdate  >= ADD_MONTHS(m.month, 1)
                OR compdate IS NULL )
       ) AS outstanding
FROM   months m
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Step, StartDate, CompDate) AS
SELECT 98775, 4.24, DATE '2023-06-28', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98776, 4.31, DATE '2023-06-28', DATE '2023-07-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98777, 4.24, DATE '2023-06-28', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98845, 4.31, DATE '2023-07-26', DATE '2023-08-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98846, 4.31, DATE '2023-07-27', DATE '2023-07-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98847, 4.24, DATE '2023-07-31', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98848, 4.31, DATE '2023-07-31', DATE '2023-08-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98853, 4.31, DATE '2023-08-03', DATE '2023-08-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98854, 4.24, DATE '2023-08-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98855, 4.23, DATE '2023-08-03', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MONTH | OUTSTANDING |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06 | 3 |
| 2023-07 | 5 |
| 2023-08 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S-lP7gj6)

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNPIVOT` the dates and then calculate a running total of the number started minus the number completed for each month:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT
        TO_CHAR(dt, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
        SUM(active) OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(dt, 'YYYY-MM')) AS outstanding
FROM    (
  SELECT startdate, compdate
  FROM   table_name
)
UNPIVOT (dt FOR active IN (startdate AS 1, compdate AS -1))
ORDER BY month;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Step, StartDate, CompDate) AS
SELECT 98775, 4.24, DATE '2023-06-28', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98776, 4.31, DATE '2023-06-28', DATE '2023-07-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98777, 4.24, DATE '2023-06-28', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98845, 4.31, DATE '2023-07-26', DATE '2023-08-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98846, 4.31, DATE '2023-07-27', DATE '2023-07-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98847, 4.24, DATE '2023-07-31', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98848, 4.31, DATE '2023-07-31', DATE '2023-08-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98853, 4.31, DATE '2023-08-03', DATE '2023-08-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98854, 4.24, DATE '2023-08-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98855, 4.23, DATE '2023-08-03', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MONTH | OUTSTANDING |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06 | 3 |
| 2023-07 | 5 |
| 2023-08 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5V9mlOZk)